# How to change the WordPress error page - "There has been a critical error on this website....."

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to change the text and link for the standard error page as shown below. And maybe change the design too.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Check your wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php file

Comment: Create a php file named “php-error.php” in your wp-content folder.  Code it with basic HTML. This will be displayed instead of the default when you encounter an error.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it thanks to @user2355051!

I'm just paraphrasing what he/she said. Create a PHP file named `php-error.php` in your `wp-content` folder.

Code it with basic HTML (really, a pure HTML page) and your error page is reborn!